# Displaying mysql data based on the username

Tags: php, mysql, session, html-table

I am new in php therefore I cannot figure out how to solve this issue.

```
<?php

    // starts a session and checks if the user is logged in

    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }


?>
```

I have a php login system which uses username and password from mysql database table called members. It uses session to see if the user is logged in.

```
<?php

    include 'booking_connection.php';


    $sql = "select id, name, room, computer_id, date, start_time, end_time from booked";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


?>



            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['room']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['computer_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['date']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['start_time']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['end_time']?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="delete.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>">CANCEL</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

<?php

    }

}


?>
```

I have another table called booked which stores information like name, id, date, computer no, start date and end date. I have a php code that displays all this information inside a table on the webpage. How would I make sure the system only displays information of a specific user based on their name.

I want to link the value of the session "username" with the value of the row "name" in the table.
for example: if the username saved on the session is "John", I would like the system to display all the information with the name John only.

Below is the full source code for that page:

```
<?php

    // starts a session and checks if the user is logged in

    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">


    <head>

                        <!-- title -->
        <title> Mycomputer </title>

                        <!-- css link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="booking.css">


    </head>

    <body>

                        <!-- headings -->       

        <h2>You have the following bookings.</h2>



                        <!-- table -->      

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>ID No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Computer ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

<?php

    include 'booking_connection.php';


    $sql = "select id, name, room, computer_id, date, start_time, end_time from booked";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


?>



            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['room']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['computer_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['date']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['start_time']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['end_time']?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="delete.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>">CANCEL</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

<?php

    }

}


?>

                </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause, while assigning a session array to the username's row.

Comment: thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sql use a `WHERE` clause to get only the filtered rows:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
    id, name, room, computer_id, date, start_time, end_time 
    FROM
    booked 
    WHERE 
    name = '" . $_SESSION['username'] ."'"
;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this answer? You made a few errors here `WHERE 
    name IS " . $_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: what error. specify what you meant. if you meant the single quotes, i have corrected it. Also this might not be a copy-paste soln. beacuse i dont know ur db schema.  You can understand the logic and implement.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause does not use `IS`. Where is that syntax from? Btw, I am not the person who posted the question. Edit: Now you used LIKE. Use `=`.

Comment: thankyou, out of all the answers here only yours worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the where clause In sql query like this

```
$sql = "select id, name, room, computer_id, date, start_time, end_time from booked where name='".$username."'  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: I am not seeing any error in this. can u tell me please where is error. $username will come from session

Comment: hi, i tired your code but it doesn't seem to work??.. its just showing me a blank page

Comment: how you are printing the data.. use echo or print_r()(for array)

Comment: other wise use foreach instead of while.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
$sql = 
"
SELECT `id`, `name`, `room`, `computer_id`, `date`, `start_time`, `end_time` FROM booked 
WHERE 
name = '".$username."' 
";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**Note:** Try to `echo` your query to see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> *Your best bet is to rethink your approach since you're working with untrusted user data.*

**Creating your Connection object using PDO (pdo_driver.php):**

```
namespace CompanyName\App\Drivers;

interface DatabaseConnection
{
    public function query($statement, array $values = array());
}

class PdoDriver implements DatabaseConnection
{
    public function __construct(
        $dsn, $user, $pass
    ) {
        try {
            parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function query(
        $statement, array $values = array()
    ) {
        $stmp = parent::Prepare($statement);
        return (empty($values)) ? $stmp->execute() : $stmp->execute($values);
    }
}
```

**Inside your then file (index.php):**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/location/to/file/pdo_driver.php';

$container = array();

// instance our object and establish connection
$container['db'] = new CompanyName\App\Drivers\PdoDriver(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password'
);

// conditional statement for readabilty
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])):
    // suggest creating a user object and using a unique session key
    // rather than a username for the session
    $current_user = $_SESSION['username']);

    $stmp = $container['db']->query('SELECT id, room, computer_id, date, start_time, end_time FROM booked WHERE name = ?', [$current_user]);
    $row = $stmp->fetch(); ?>

    <table id=''>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
            <!-- Continue adding these -->
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Why use PDO and what's the advantages of OOP (Object-oriented programming) ?**

PDO is a secure layer which is least depreciated in PHP that uses the basic mysql protocols. Using Object oriented programming allows you to build framework (or an infrastructure) which can then be imported into multiple projects.

I also suggest building some sort of DI software or using prebuilt DI software like Symfony.

Comment: any time, I suggest edging towards a more oop approach since your code is precedural and lacks readabilty @katetango